# How to update pandas when python is installed as part of ArcGIS10.4, or another solution

Tags: python, pandas, upgrade, arcmap

I recently installed ArcGIS10.4 and now when I run python 2.7 programs using Idle (for purposes unrelated to ArcGIS) it uses the version of python attached to ArcGIS.

One of the programs I wrote needs an updated version of the pandas module. When I try to update the pandas module in this verion of python (by opening command prompt as an administrator, moving to C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Scripts and using the command pip install --upgrade pandas) the files download ok but there is an access error message when PIP tries to upgrade. I have tried restarting the computer in case something was open.  The error message is quite long and I can't cut and paste from command prompt but it finishes with 
" Permission denied:  'C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.pyd'  "

I've tried the command to reinstall pandas completely which also gave an error message.  I've tried installing miniconda in the hope that I could get a second version of python working and then use that version instead of the version attached to ArcMap. However I don't know how to direct Idle to choose the newly installed version.

So overall I don't mind having 2 versions of python if someone could tell me how to choose which one runs or if there's some way to update the ArcMap version that would be even better. I don't really want to uninstall ArcMap at the moment.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled python again directly from python.org and then installed pandas which seems to work.

I guess this might stop the ArcMap version of python working properly but since I'm not using python with ArcMap at the moment it's not a big problem.

Comment: so annoying, I having the same problem again 4 years later :(  and just came across my own question!